# Does "probably" sound natural in this context?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

> When he was put in a coma, was it clear from the beginning that he
>   **probably** wouldn’t make it? Or what did the doctors tell you?

Is "probably" natural to use here? Is it placed correctly?

Comment: It is in the correct position for the grammar to make sense. Another option for a commonly-used word in this instance is `likely`/`unlikely`:

When he was put in a coma, was it clear from the beginning that it was unlikely he would make it?

Comment: It is fine. But why are you hesitant? Do you have something else in mind?